# Logging into a website with Python using requests, how do you resolve what needs to be sent?

Tags: python, forms, python-requests, lxml

I'm using the following script to attempt a site login with the requests library for this website: https://cas.shopatron.com/cas/login

However, I always seem to get the login page as the response, so I'm thinking my payload is off. How do I determine what's required in the payload? Or am I missing something else here?

Script:

```
import requests
from lxml import html




login_url = 'https://cas.shopatron.com/cas/login'
authd_url = 'https://www.shopatron.com/rtl/'
name = '*****'
password = '*****'



payload = {
    "username": name, 
    "password": password,
    "submit" : "Submit",
    "lt": "LT-1426788-q3xOkNQDdGN7wB0AJMAKkegYKNosBN-i-f1229b28",
    "execution": "e12s1",
    "_eventId": "submit"
}


session_requests = requests.session()


result = session_requests.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)


result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = payload, 
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

resultauthd = session_requests.get(authd_url)

print resultauthd
print resultauthd.encoding
print resultauthd.content
print resultauthd.headers
```

Comment: Any well-writtens site will send a unique CSRF token with every form. You'll need to send the correct value back

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to scrape the validation values from the hidden fields on the form for every login.  You might also need to include the session ID which is sent in the request, as well as a value for the "remember me" box.

You might find the Python module robobrowser useful to prevent you from having to go through all of this (and it uses Requests):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robobrowser

Answer (score 1):

The payload you need to send changes everytime you access the login URL (keys `lt`, `execution` and `_eventId`). You need to extract this "CSRF" data (input type="hidden") and send it as a payload automatically on the POST request. You can extract the payload by using XPath like this:

```
import requests
import lxml.etree

LOGIN_URL = 'https://cas.shopatron.com/cas/login'
session = requests.session()

# Get CSRF data
response = session.get(LOGIN_URL)
html = lxml.etree.HTML(response.text)
hidden_elements = html.xpath('//input[@type="hidden"]')
form_data = {elem.attrib['name']: elem.attrib['value']
             for elem in hidden_elements}
```

Than you just need to add username and password data and issue the POST request:

```
form_data['username'] = '***PUT-USERNAME-HERE***'
form_data['password'] = '***PUT-PASSWORD-HERE***'
response = session.post(LOGIN_URL, form_data)
```